# Rails select_tag in form group, input group, no param sent

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, select, bootstrap-4

I have got a form with a select_tag and dynamic values, like below:

```
   <% listed = @customers.find_all { |customer| customer.status_trust == 'blacklist' || customer.status_trust == 'whitelist' || customer.status_trust == 'graylist' } %>
    <% @reasons = listed.map { |customer| customer.status_trust_reason }.uniq %>
    <div class="col-md-2"> 
      <%= form_tag admin_status_export_path, method: :post do %>
      <div class="form-group">
      <%= label_tag 'Exportações'  %> <br/>
        <div class="input-group">
        <%= select_tag(:status_trust_reason, options_for_select(@reasons.map { |reason| reason }, params[:status_trust_reason]), prompt: 'All', class: 'form-control shadow-sm form-control-sm') %>
        <div class="input-group-append"> 
        <%= link_to admin_status_export_path, class: 'btn btn-sm btn-dark ml-4', name: 'action_btn', type: 'submit', method: :post do %>
        <%= icon('fas', 'file-excel ', ' Exportaçõ') %>
        <% end %>
        </div>
        </div> 
        </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div> # inner row end
</div>
```

# outer row end

listed gets the listed items with those values, and @reasons put in to an array with each value, depending how many are in use at the time.

All this is inside an inner bootstrap row with the first parts used in filters a form tag and a get method for them, whereas this has a post method, input group and route on the button. It is not sending the selected value, which for now want to render json whatever is selected. Am wondering if some conflict due to the earlier form_tag, although it ends prior, it is in the same row, or some other reason?

We have to have listed as it is above rather than Customer.all as this syncs it with the earlier filters, the actual status_trusts.

Any tips welcome it is the last bit to get this working! Thanks

Comment: It looks like you have a `select_tag` and `link_to`, but they aren't in a `form_tag`. I don't see a form at all and I don't see a `submit` tag

Comment: [Here's the form guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-basic-forms)

Comment: Fixed the above is submitting , think a turbolink issue now, Thanks

Comment: Can you post the actual form? The params from the controller that receives the form data?